# Find the presence of other turtles in a given direction upto a distance

Tags: netlogo

I wish to find out whether in a given turtle's heading there is another agent present upto a given distance.[image]

Here the Distance is "D".

**Note:**

Any agent present before D in the given direction should be also considered.

Even the direction doesn't coincide with the other's agent centre but just touches it ,even then that agent should be considered.

**Problem:**

No turtle-ahead procedure available. Combination of patch-ahead and turtles-on not applicable due to patch-size>> turtle-size.
[image]
**Possible approach:**
1.Represent the turtle's heading by the equation of a line.

```
to-report calculate-line[x y angle]
  let m tan angle
  let A m 
  let B -1 
  let C (- m * x + y) 
report (list A B C)
end
to-report heading-to-angle [ h ]
  report (90 - h) mod 360
end
```

> let line-equ calculate-line (xcor) (ycor) (heading-to-angle heading)

2.Calculate the perpendicular distance from other turtles here, Check if there are within a range that the size of other turtles.

```
to-report value[A X1 Y1];;A is list of coefficents of line, x1 and y1 are coordinates of red turtle
  if-else(abs((item 0 A * X1 + item 1 A * Y1 + item 2 A) / (sqrt((item 0 A ^ 2) + (item 1 A ^ 2) ))) < [size] of wall )
 [ report "true"][report "false"]
```

end

3.To check if the red turtle is within D. One could obtain a line perpendicular to black one and compute the red turtle distance from it to check if it is less than or equal to D. But then that adds more complication.(Though one can simplify rotate the turtle by 90 left or right and get the line equation.)

Comment: I think you're just going to have to grind out the math on this.

Comment: you could use the combination of patch-ahead and turtles-on to identify which turtles to test for collision. One problem you will have is that the 'just touch' requirement means that the distance is important. That is, whether you would touch the edge of a turtle depends on how far away it is.

Comment: @JenB I have tried one rough possible approach, but it seems complicated. Please have a look.

Comment: @SethTisue What about an approach in which you hatch a turtle given location and then fd upto a distance D. And check overlap at each step.

Comment: Sure, that's a good idea. Take a step, use `in-radius`. Take another step, use `in-radius` again, and so on. I hadn't thought of that. It's an approximation, but it might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: @JenB But, since patch-size>>turtle-size. I don't contemplate how the combination of patch-ahead and turtles-on  could be helpful.

Comment: @SethTisue There must some other way. Is it possible to create to links to all other turtles in a given turtle's direction but upto only a certain distance?

Comment: Only if you know how to compute that set of turtles. You're just restating the question.

Comment: @SethTisue I think I didn't elucidate it well enough. 1.Create a turtle at distance d from the present(hatch 1 fd d). 2.Create link to that turtle from the original. 3. Somehow check if other turtles intersect this link.(Which is not possible from what I know.)

Comment: Making the link doesn't buy you anything that I can see.

Comment: @SethTisue Yeah you're right. I was looking a procedure that tells if any other turtles lies on a single link. Note:Lies definitely doesn't mean it is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   to-report check-wall 
   let return false
  hatch 1[
    set color black
    set size ([size] of one-of walls) / 2
    show (2.5 * ([size] of myself))
    while [distance myself < (2.5 * ([size] of myself))]
    [

      fd ([size] of one-of walls) / 64
      if any? walls in-radius size
      [
        set return true
        ]
      show distance myself
      ]

    ]
  report return
  end
```

The above works. But still is approx. I am looking for better solution with probably less maths as one elucidated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I meant by my comment. Run this code (as its own model). What it does is turn all the turtles on a few 'ahead' patches a different colour. I know this is not what you are trying to do, but the agentset candidates is a relatively small number of turtles. These are the only ones that you have to check whether they are on the correct path. So instead of turning them a different colour you could check the direction that they are from your initial turtle.

```
to setup
  clear-all
  set-patch-size 25
  resize-world -10 10 -10 10
  create-turtles 1000
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color yellow
    set size 0.4
  ]
  ask one-of turtles
  [ set color red
    set size 1
    check-from-me 5
  ]
end

to check-from-me [howfar]
  let counter 0
  let candidates turtles-here
  while [counter < howfar]
  [ set counter counter + 1
    set candidates (turtle-set candidates turtles-on patch-ahead counter)
  ]
  ask candidates [set color red]
end
```